# How to show expectation of exponential related to Bessel process is finite

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-analysis

My problem originates from the following expression (and a slight lack of deeper knowledge in probability theory):

$\mathbb{E}[\exp{(8\theta Y_{t})}]$, where

$$Y_{t}:=\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{s}\frac{W_{s}-W_{r}-y}{\vert W_{s}-W_{r}-y\vert^{2}}\:dr\:dW_{s}$$

and $W_{s}$ is a 2-dimensional Brownian motion.

My goal is to show that (for $ \theta < \theta_{0}$) it is finite. I already managed to show that if one is able to proof this for the quadratic variation of the term in the exponent, one obtains the existence of such a $\theta_{0}$. So I need to show the following:$\mathbb{E}[\exp{(\gamma C\langle Y_{t} \rangle)}]<\infty$ for some $\gamma$. If my estimates are correct,
$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp{\left(\gamma C \sum_{i=1}^{2}\int_{0}^{t}\left(\int_{0}^{s}\frac{(W_{s}-W_{r}-y)_{i}}{\vert W_{s}-W_{r}-y\vert^{2}}\:dr\right)^{2}\:ds_{i} \right)}\right]\leq \mathbb{E}\left[\exp{\left( C\gamma\int_{0}^{t}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{\vert W_{s}-W_{s-r}-y\vert}\:dr\right)^{2}\:ds\right)}\right]$

$\leq \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\gamma Ct\left(\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{\vert W_{r}-y\vert}\:dr\right)^{2}\right)\right]$.

I already found out, that I could use Ito's formula, applied to a 2-dimensional Bessel process($X_{t}$), to reformulate the term in the integral
:$\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{\vert W_{r}-y\vert}\:dr\right)=X_{t}-\vert y\vert-B_{t}$,
where $B_{t}:=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{2}W^{i}_{t}\:dW^{i}_{t}}{\vert W_{t}\vert}$ is a 1-dimensional Brownian motion.

This is the point where I am stuck, as I don't see an easy way to evaluate the square of this expression.